# How to force Windows 7 to find files that has the text I am searching in their name?

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, windows-search

I remember clearly either XP or Windows 7 worked like this because. Basically if I were to search for "replace" in a folder, it shows "No files".

But if I search for "*replace", then it shows 2 files:

```
MusicReplacer.txt
MusicReplacer.png
```

Is this normal? I know how to use wildcards but this should be the default behavior. How can I force Windows 7 to search like this so it always finds files that has the text I am searching for, anywhere in their name. Because that's all I care.

Comment: use 3rd party searches. The Search is crap since Vista. I use this tool: http://www.voidtools.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will download it. Shame that MS can't even get this right with all their money and power.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the search settings have been modified. By default, they are set to show partial matches.

To change search settings, go to Tools -> Folder Options. On the Search tab, under "How to Search", check the "Find partial matches" checkbox.

As for @magicandre1981's assertion that it is crap, I disagree. If you do not have it set to indexing, it may be slow, but it is accurate, and in my experience works well.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't modify the search settings. I just looked at them and Find partial matches was checked. But it still doesn't find partial matches, it's very frustrating because I thought the files didn't exist, but they do.

Comment: I actually agree 100% with @magicandre1981's evaluation of Win7 Search. It can't do even [relatively](http://superuser.com/questions/538670) [simple](http://superuser.com/questions/514331) things easily, and as for complex searches the less said the better. I'd ditch AQS (which I bet 99% people haven't even heard of, let alone used) in a heartbeat if simple regex was supported instead.